# How to change value for object property in array if property not match with compared value?

Tags: javascript

I want to return array with properties which not matched by `valuesToCompare` array values

```js
const arr = [
{value: "test1", name: "name1"},
{value: "test2", name: "name1"},
{value: "test3", name: "name1"},
{value: "test3", name: "name2"},
{value: "test4", name: "name2"},
]

const valuesToCompare = ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"]
```

**expected output**

```
[
{value: "test4", name: "name1"},
{value: "test1", name: "name2"},
{value: "test2", name: "name2"},
]
```

Comment: The question isn't clear, explain it better

Comment: What is the logic behind matching?

Comment: Need details or clarity. valuesToCompare  contains test3 then why is it not a part of the output?

Comment: i want to return  values which was not existed in values in `arr`

Comment: Yeah, it's neither excluding nor matching valuesToCompare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do like below:

- group the `arr` by `name`
- with each grouped, filter the value
- flatten each group back into objects

```js
const arr = [
  { value: "test1", name: "name1" },
  { value: "test2", name: "name1" },
  { value: "test3", name: "name1" },
  { value: "test3", name: "name2" },
  { value: "test4", name: "name2" },
];

const valuesToCompare = ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"];

const groupByName = arr.reduce((acc, el) => {
  if (acc[el.name]) {
    acc[el.name].push(el.value);
  } else {
    acc[el.name] = [el.value];
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

const res = Object.entries(groupByName)
  .map(([k, v]) => [k, valuesToCompare.filter((vtc) => !v.includes(vtc))])
  .map(([k, v]) => v.map((v) => ({ name: k, value: v })))
  .flat();

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether you want to match or exclude based on an array of values, so providing both:

```js
const arr = [{
    value: "test1",
    name: "name1"
  },
  {
    value: "test2",
    name: "name1"
  },
  {
    value: "test3",
    name: "name1"
  },
  {
    value: "test3",
    name: "name2"
  },
  {
    value: "test4",
    name: "name2"
  },
]

const valuesToCompare = ["test1", "test2"]

const excluding = arr.filter(obj => !valuesToCompare.includes(obj.value))

console.log("Excluding values:")
console.log(excluding)

const matching = arr.filter(obj => valuesToCompare.includes(obj.value))

console.log("Matching values:")
console.log(matching)
```